# Missing /var/log/mail.log (after deleting it) - How do I recreate it?

Tags: email, ubuntu-14.04

To clear the mail log I deleted `/var/log/mail.log` and `/var/log/mail.err`.

Now it seems like I've broken something as the files are not recreated as I interact with `mail`:

```
kidmose@radagast:~$ echo "Test text" | mail -s "From radagast" kidmose@gmail.com
kidmose@radagast:~$ cat /var/log/mail.log
cat: /var/log/mail.log: No such file or directory
```

**Any ideas as how to make logging work again?**

(Ideally without reinstall or reboot)

My setup:

```
kidmose@radagast:~$ uname -a
Linux radagast 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
kidmose@radagast:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Remove the files belonging to root (If there), as suggested by @Dan.
2. Restart MTA(sendmail in my case) and syslog, as suggested by @drookie

   ```
   sudo service sendmail restart 
   sudo service rsyslog restart
   ```

Bonus info: 
The files will then be created as syslog:adm

Answer (score 5):

`touch /var/log/mail.log /var/log/mail.err`, then restart whatever is writing to them, like your MTA or syslog.

Comment: Restarted sendmail and rsyslog(`sudo service sendmail restart` and `sudo service rsyslog restart`) to no avail.

Comment: If you did not forcefully created them with the `touch` commands, restarting syslog should do the trick (depending on the configuration, syslog may not create them as root)

Comment: @Dan: You're right, solved it.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS:

1. touch /var/log/mail.log /var/log/mail.err
2. chown syslog:adm /var/log/mail.log /var/log/mail.err
3. service postfix reload

After those three commands you should have new records inside of /var/log/mail.log:

> Jan 18 05:14:21 ubuntu-srv postfix/master[9405]: reload -- version 3.1.0,
>   configuration /etc/postfix

---

Another way to see some short history of necessary logs including whats happeinging postfix is the **journalctl** command

Answer (score 0):

In my case, ubuntu 8 (i know old one...)
1. Restart OS.
2. touch /var/log/mail.log 
3. chown syslog:adm /var/log/mail.log

mail.log is now filling with data...
It was big relief.
Aleksej

Comment: Step 1 should have been sufficient on its own.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped only this one command `service rsyslog restart` and mail.log was created and written ok, because `touch /var/mail.log` just created file but was never written and restart or stop/start of postfix did not solved it. After `service rsyslog restart` free space reported by `df` was finally released. Before I had free space just 3GB and after `service rsyslog restart` 6 GB. I was not able to detect what occupies too many space. It was huge mail.log which was deleted but free space never released. Strange.